# Automatically Run Contract

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, private-blockchain, contract-invocation

I have a private ethereum network made up of multiple nodes and I would like one of them to interact with the a deployed smart contract without my input. Is it possible for create a script that will write to and read from a smart contract once an hour?

Comment: Of course it is possible! For example, with web3.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script which will trigger a running node API which uses web3 js library 
or else you can make use of Ethereum Alarm clock in order to trigger a smart contract function based upon block,time values.